# Cypress and Excel Test Data

Tags: cypress

Has anyone used excel to store test data while runing cypress tests? I am trying to make this work, but since I cant access the file system with browserify I cant read excel test data file. Anyone got this working? DO you have any links/code on how to get it working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that normal excel processing packages wont work with cypress and typescript, since u r using browserfiy. browserify will prevent you from performing file read/write operations.

as a workaround, i only read the excel file prior to browserifying it (in the plugins/index.js), and convert it into a json file and save it in the fixtures folder.

then in the support/index.js in a beforeAll hook i read the json file as a fixture and save it to an aliased variable. Now I can parse data from the aliased variable and use it where required in cypress context throughout the test. this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an instruction how to use excel as source for cypress tests https://medium.com/@you54f/dynamically-generate-data-in-cypress-from-csv-xlsx-7805961eff55

First you need to convert your xlsx file to json with Xlsx

> ```js
> import { writeFileSync } from "fs";
> import * as XLSX from "xlsx";
> try {
>   const workBook = XLSX.readFile("./testData/testData.xlsx");
>   const jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workBook.Sheets.testData);
>   writeFileSync(
>     "./cypress/fixtures/testData.json",
>     JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 4),
>     "utf-8"
>   );
> } catch (e) {
>   throw Error(e);
> }
> ```

Then import json file and loop over each row and use the data in the way you want. In this example it tries to log in to a system.

> ```js
> import { login } from "../support/pageObjects/login.page";
> const testData = require("../fixtures/testData.json");
> describe("Dynamically Generated Tests", () => {
>   testData.forEach((testDataRow: any) => {
>     const data = {
>       username: testDataRow.username,
>       password: testDataRow.password
>     };
>     context(`Generating a test for ${data.username}`, () => {
>       it("should fail to login for the specified details", () => {
>         login.visit();
>         login.username.type(data.username);
>         login.password.type(`${data.password}{enter}`);
>         login.errorMsg.contains("Your username is invalid!");
>         login.logOutButton.should("not.exist");
>       });
>     });
>   });
> });
> ```